# Join two tables and show Columns of one table as Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There are two tables which I have to join and produce the expected result

Employee Table

```
EmpID   | EmpName
1       | Adam
2       | Eve
3       | John
4       | Steve
```

EmployeeNationality Table

```
EmpID   | Nationality
1       | US
1       | UK
1       | UKraine
2       | US
3       | Canada
4       | Spain
```

Result Expected

```
EmpID   | EmpName   | Nationality1  | Nationality2 
1       | Adam      | US            | UK
2       | Eve       | US            | 
3       | John      | Canada        | 
4       | Steve     | Spain         |
```

Though there are three records for Employee ID 1 (Adam) I always have to show only two Nationality so the no of columns are fixed. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: So if one "has" three nationalities you want to omit the last? Which one?

Comment: As of now it is not a problem I can omit any but I prefer to omit the first one

Comment: So what column do you want to use for the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need two nationalities:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT e.EmpID, 
         e.EmpName, 
         en.Nationality,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmpID,e.EmpName
                                 ORDER BY e.EmpID)
  FROM   dbo.employee e 
         INNER JOIN employeenationality en 
                 ON e.empid = en.empid
)
SELECT DISTINCT c1.EmpID, c1.EmpName,
       Nationality1 = (SELECT Nationality FROM CTE Nationality1
                       WHERE c1.EmpID = Nationality1.EmpID
                       AND   Nationality1.RN = 1),
       Nationality2 = (SELECT Nationality FROM CTE Nationality2
                       WHERE c1.EmpID = Nationality2.EmpID
                       AND   Nationality2.RN = 2)
FROM CTE c1
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78182/14/0)</kbd>

Otherwise use [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).